# Django Image is not saving

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on a website, where you can upload a project. Each project contains a name, description, image and a deadline, that you can set.

When i try to upload a project by pressing the "Save Project" button, i get redirected to my homepage as expected, but the image does not get saved, everything else does. I dont get any error message.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True,)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name

class Image(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_images')
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from .models import Project, Image

class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_name', 'project_description', 'deadline']
        widgets = {
            'deadline': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }

ImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Project, Image, fields=('image',), extra=5, can_delete=True,)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .models import Project
from .forms import ProjectForm, ImageFormSet

def homepage(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    context = {
        'projects': projects,
    }
    return render(request, 'project.html', context)

def create_project(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        project_form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if project_form.is_valid():
            project = project_form.save()
            formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=project)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
                return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000')
    else:
        project_form = ProjectForm()
        formset = ImageFormSet()

    context = {
        'project_form': project_form,
        'formset': formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'create_project.html', context)
```

create_project.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Create Project</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Create Project</h1>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="{{ project_form.project_name.id_for_label }}">Project name:</label>
        {{ project_form.project_name }}
        <br>
        <label for="{{ project_form.project_description.id_for_label }}">Project description:</label>
        {{ project_form.project_description }}
        <br>
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        <div id="image-container"></div>
        <br>
        <label for="{{ project_form.deadline.id_for_label }}">Deadline:</label>
        {{ project_form.deadline }}
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="add-image-btn">Add Image</button>
        <button type="submit">Save Project</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const addImageBtn = document.getElementById('add-image-btn');
            const imageContainer = document.getElementById('image-container');
    
            let imageCount = 0;
    
            addImageBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                // Checks if imagefield is empty
                const previousImageInput = document.querySelector(`[name="form-${imageCount-1}-image"]`);
                if (previousImageInput && previousImageInput.value === '') {
                    alert('Add a image to the existing field, before creating a new one.');
                    return;
                }
    
                if (imageCount < 5) {
                    const newImageRow = document.createElement('div');
                    newImageRow.className = 'image-row';
                    const label = document.createElement('label');
                    label.textContent = 'Image:';
                    const imageInput = document.createElement('input');
                    imageInput.type = 'file';
                    imageInput.name = `form-${imageCount}-image`;
                    const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
                    deleteBtn.type = 'button';
                    deleteBtn.className = 'delete-image-btn';
                    deleteBtn.textContent = 'Delete Image';
                    newImageRow.appendChild(label);
                    newImageRow.appendChild(imageInput);
                    newImageRow.appendChild(deleteBtn);
                    imageContainer.appendChild(newImageRow);
                    imageCount++;
                }
            });
    
            imageContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                if (event.target.className === 'delete-image-btn') {
                    const imageRow = event.target.parentNode;
                    imageRow.remove();
                    imageCount--;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    

</body>

</html>
```

project.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Create Projects</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="/create_project"><h2>Create a new project</h2></a>

    <h1>Projects</h1>

    {% for project in projects|dictsortreversed:"created_at" %}
        <div>
            <hr>
            <h2>{{ project.project_name }}</h2>
            <p>{{ project.project_description }}</p>
            <p>Created at: {{ project.created_at }}</p>
            {% if project.deadline %}
                <p>Deadline: {{ project.deadline }}</p>
            {% endif %}
            {% for image in project.project_images.all %}
                {% if image.image %}
                    <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="Project Picture could not be loaded" style="max-width: 500px;">
                {% else %}
                    <p>No image available for this project.</p>
                {% endif %}
            {% empty %}
                <p>No images available for this project.</p>
            {% endfor %}
            <a href="{% url 'edit_project' project.id %}">Bearbeiten</a>
            <br>
        </div>
    {% empty %}
        <p>Keine Projekte vorhanden.</p>
    {% endfor %}
</body>

</html>
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('projekte.urls')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='index'),
    path('delete_picture/<int:project_id>/', views.delete_picture, name='delete_picture'),
    path('edit_project/<int:project_id>/', views.edit_project, name='edit_project'),
    path('delete_project/<int:project_id>/', views.delete_project, name='delete_project'),
    path('create_project', views.create_project, name='create_project'),

]
```

In models i defined two models, Project and Image. "Project" handels the project name, description, creation date and the deadline. "Image" contains an Imagefield and has a Foreignkey relationship with Project.

Forms has a class called Projectform using a Modelform. I made it associated with the model Project. After that i made an inline formset factory using inlineformset_factory for the Project and Image models, so it can handle many images for one project.

In view there are two functions. One of them is homepage which retrieves all projects from the database, passes them to project.html. Which then shows everything, such as name, image...
The second function "create_project" handles both GET and POST requests for creating a new project.
When a POST request is made, it validates the ProjectForm and the associated ImageFormSet.
If both forms are valid, it should save the project and the associated images, and then redirects to the homepage. When a GET request is made, it creates instances of ProjectForm and ImageFormSet to display empty forms for creating a new project. The forms are passed as context data to the create_project.html template for rendering.

Create_project.html is a basic HTML template for creating a project. It includes a form with fields for project name, description, deadline, and an option to add multiple images.
The form uses the POST method and enctype multipart/form-data for handling file uploads.

The script section at the bottom contains code that when the "Add Image" button is clicked, the code checks - If the previous image input field is empty. If it is, an alert is shown, and a new image field is not created. This ensures that users fill out the previous image field before adding a new one.

- If the previous image input field is not empty and the total image count is less than 5, a new image field is created. Each image field consists of a label, an input field of type "file," and a delete button.
  The Add image button also creates a delete image button. It removes the corresponding image field from the DOM and decreases the image count.

Thats atleast what i tried, but it doesnt save the image and doesnt get saved into the database.
Just a guess, but i think the problem may lie in the create_project.html file, since it has been able to save multiple images, but after some changes in the  and adding a  it broke and i wasnt able to fix it.
My goal is when i press "Save Project", that also images get saved not only the name, description, deadline, creation date.

Screenshot of input form:

[image]

Screenshot of homepage after saving a project:

[image]

Thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 0):

by refering project in `.save` method

```
formset.save(project=project)
```

It works when using fileForm as modelForm
anyway why don't you put imagefield on **project model**?

Comment: The reason the ImageField is not directly included in the Project model is because it allows for a one-to-many relationship between a project and multiple images. By using a separate Image model with a foreign key to the Project model, you can associate multiple images with a single project. Atleast thats the tought behind it